# Error when executing batch file from a .CHM file

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file, powerpoint, chm

I have a CHM help file that has a few clickable links to powerpoint presentations which are resting in the same directory. However, when I click the link from the CHM file, I get the following error:

Unable to start TestCase-play.bat

where TestCase-play.bat runs pptview.exe and opens a powerpoint presentation both of which are also in the same directory with all required libraries. I know CHM files work with external links as long as they are in the same directory, but is there any reason a BAT file won't be executed? And if so, is there a way around this?

Comment: Can't you just start the program directly?

Comment: You might have to run it via an explicit invocation of _cmd.exe_ : `cmd /c TestCase-play.bat param1 param2`.

Comment: We ended up just directing the end-user to the powerpoint examples, but I am still interested in a solution to this.

Also, i don't think I can just run CMD.EXE with arguments passed to it from a CHM file.

Comment: bobbogo: there is a simple test for that. If links to files with known extensions (but specially ones that are not known by a new install of windows) work, then one shouldn't need cmd /c, since probably shellexecute is used. If it doesn't work, createprocess is used, and one needs cmd /c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since CHM files are very limited in what you can do, we migrated our documentation to HTML so we could put in flash demos and embed PPT slides for certain topics. Doesn't really answer my original question, but even if I did solve it, I think this is a better route to go for help pages.